# Show that $R\cong Re\times R(1-e)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, idempotents

An element $e\in R$  is called *idempotent* if $e^2=e$. Assume that $e$ is idempotent and $er=re$ $\forall r\in R$. Prove that $Re$ and $R(1-e)$   are two sided ideals of $R$ and $R\cong  Re\times R(1-e)$.

I  have successfully proved the other results and stuck on the last one. Applying Chinese Remainder Theorem we have that $R/(Re\cap R(1-e))\cong R/Re\times R/R(1-e)$ .

Also $Re+R(1-e)=R$ and $Re\cap R(1-e)=\{0\}$. Thus $R\cong  R/Re\times R/R(1-e)$.

where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f=1-e$, so that $ef=fe$ and $f^2=f,e^2=e$. We have a morphism of rings (prove it is one!) $R\to Re\times Rf$ that sends $a=ae+af$ to $ (af,ae)$. The rings $Re$ and $Rf$ have units $e,f$ respectively. This is an epimorphism since $ae+bf$ maps to $(ae,bf)$ (for $ef=fe=0$ and $f,e$ are idempotent), and a monomorphism since $af=ae=0$ gives $af+ae=a=0$. The point of this is you don't need to meddle with CRT and all those isomorphism theorems: central idempotents disconnect your ring "nicely" and you can make concrete computations with them.

Comment: Do you mean the map $a \mapsto (ae, af)$?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof using the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

As $e$ is idempotent, we have that $e(1-e) = e - e^2 = e - e = 0$.

Now, $R \cong R/(0) \cong R/(e(1-e))$

Note that $(e)$ and $(1-e)$ are comaximal because $1-e+e = 1 \in (e(1-e))$.

Thus, by the Chinese remainder theorem, we have:
$$R \cong R/(e) \times R/(1-e)$$
$$or \; R \cong R/Re \times R/R(1-e)$$

We now claim that $R/Re \cong R(1-e)$ and $R/R(1-e) \cong Re$.
$$$$

Define $\phi: R \to R(1-e)$ by $r \mapsto r(1-e)$

Clearly, $\phi$ is onto and it is easy to verify that it is a ring homomorphism.

$ker \; \phi = \{ r\in R: r(1-e) = 0\}$

Let $x \in Re$. Then $x = re$ for some $r \in R$. Then $\phi(x) = re(1-e) = re - re^2 = re - re = 0$.

$\implies x \in \ker \; \phi$, or $Re \subseteq ker \; \phi$.

For the other inclusion, let $r \in \ker \; \phi$. Then $r = r\cdot 1 = r[e+(1-e)] = re + r(1-e) = re$ (as $r \in ker \; \phi, r(1-e) = 0$).

$\implies r \in Re$, or $\ker \; \phi \subseteq Re$

So, we have $ker \; \phi = Re$, and by the first isomorphism theorem, $R/Re \cong R(1-e)$.

Similarly, you can show that $R/R(1-e) \cong Re$.
$$$$
So, we finally have that $R \cong Re \times R(1-e). \; \blacksquare$